# How can I dynamically select a class property using a string variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose my class has a couple of similar properties and I want to select one dynamically based on a string variable:

**MyClass properties:**
PropertyOne
PropertyTwo

**Some generic code:**
myString = "One"
MyClass.Property & myString = "blah" 'this doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CallByName MyClass, "PropertyOne", vbLet, "blah"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/callbyname-function

Comment: Can I do something like this: CallByName MyClass, Property & myString, vbLet, "blah"

Comment: @user5689314 yes but it has to be a string: `"Property" & myString`